# Defining probability events

Tags: probability

I'm having a little bit of an issue testing my understanding of probability and defining of the events. Take this example:

$N_i$ = “at least i households don’t put out their normal rubbish bin”

$R_i$ =  “at least i households don’t put out their recycled rubbish bin”

$G_i$ = “at least i household don’t put out their green waste bin”

Okay so they are the events. Cool.

But here is what will help me understand some of the types of questions we're asked.

(a) every household puts out their normal rubbish bin

(b) at most four households don’t put out their green waste bin

(c) exactly six household don’t put out their recycled rubbish bin

(d) at least one of each type of bin won’t be put out for the whole shift

(e) at least one bin won’t be put out for the whole shift

(f) every household puts out all three of their bins

(g) exactly three of each type of bin won’t be put out for the whole shift

(h) exactly one bin won’t be put out for the whole shift

Now, my first thought for (a) would be $\bar N_i$

As for the rest? well I'm afraid I need to ask for a little help. I'm sure many of you will find these questions very easy so I apologise.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hello Geekbabe, we are here to help you. But to do so, we ask you to tell us what you have tried and what exactly your problems are. (a) is correct. So what are your ideas for the other questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to induce random variables $X_N, X_R, X_G$ taking values in $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ that denote the number of households that do not put out their normal, recycled, green bin respectively.

Then $N_i=\{X_N\geq i\}$, $R_i=\{X_R\geq i\}$ and $G_i=\{X_G\geq i\}$.

(a) $\{X_N=0\}=\{X_N\geq 1\}^c=N_1^c$

(b) $\{X_G\leq4\}=\{X_G\geq5\}^c=G_5^c$

(c) $\{X_R=6\}=\{X_R\geq6\}\cap\{X_R\geq7\}^c=R_6\cap R_7^c$

Try this out on the other exercises. If you get stuck somewhere then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys after a little deliberation I believe these are the answers. I hope these offer clarification to anyone that may use this thread in the future.

(a) $\bar{N_1}$

(b) $\bar{G_5}$

(c) $R_6 \cap \bar{R_7}$

(d) $N_1 \cap R_1 \cap G_1$

(e) $N_1 \cup R_1 \cup G_1$

(f) $\bar{N_1} \cap \bar{R_1} \cap \bar{G_1}$ (*De Morgan's Law could apply here)*

(g) $(\bar{R_4} \cap R_3) \cap (\bar{G_4}\cap G_3) \cap (\bar{N_4}\cap N_3)$

(h) $(N_1 \cap \bar{N_2}) \cup (R_1 \cap \bar{R_2})\cup (G_1 \cap \bar{G_2})$

$\cap  \overline{  [(N_1 \cap \bar{N_2} \cap G_1 \cap \bar{G_2}) \cup (N_1 \cap \bar{N_2}\cap R_1 \cap \bar{R_2})\cup(R_1 \cap \bar{R_2}\cap G_1 \cap \bar{G_2})]} $

Comment: $\bar{N}_{i}$ for a)? What is the value of $i$? I hope/suspect it is a typo.

Comment: Yes, it was. Edited.

Comment: Excellent. Alternative for h): $\left(N_{1}\cap N_{2}^{c}\cap R_{1}^{c}\cap B_{1}^{c}\right)\cup\left(N_{1}^{c}\cap R_{1}\cap R_{2}^{c}\cap B_{1}^{c}\right)\cup\left(N_{1}^{c}\cap R_{1}^{c}\cap B_{1}\cap B_{2}^{c}\right)$